# AIDE "Unknown entity 'R'" Error with Android Studio App Project

Tags: android, android-studio, aide-ide

I am trying to work on an Android App that I started writing with Android Studio using AIDE, but I have an issue with the project throwing an `Unknown entity 'R'` error in AIDE that I never saw in Android Studio. I would imagine that somehow, Android Studio uses Gradle to manage this and prevent this from being an issue, but since AIDE does not support Gradle, the project does not function properly.

What must I do to make the project work in AIDE while still maintaining compatibility with Android Studio? This seems to be an issue that others have experienced, but I have been unable to find a solution to the problem.

[image: AIDE Project Screenshot]

Comment: @AimanB Running "Refresh Build" does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Where are the `/build` folder and the `R`class located in the Android Studio project?

Comment: @MikeM. The folder is located in `/app/build` and the `R` class is located at `/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/stackoverflow/davidb/R.java`.

Comment: Yeah, AIDE probably can't find it, as that's a different directory structure than it uses. Try deleting the entire `/build` directory, and rebuild.

Comment: @MikeM. Even after deleting the `/build` directory, there's still a problem, although the file is now at `/app/build/gen/stackoverflow/davidb/R.java`.

Comment: Yep, that's where it should be. Still the same error? Try adding `import stackoverflow.davidb.R;` to your class.

Comment: @MikeM. Still the same error, and the `import` does not change anything.

Comment: Are you getting an error on the `import` statement? I'm not that familiar with gradle, but check those files for anything that might be specifying a build or resource location.

Comment: @MikeM. Everything's all right. I made a stupid mistake with the `import` statement. Now the question is if the project will still work with Android Studio.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd just have to rebuild in Android Studio to re-create those directories it's expecting. Nothing else really changed.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to keep adding and removing the `import` statements. Anyway, it does not matter. I will harness the power Git to maintain two branches: one for Android Studio and one for AIDE.

Comment: The `import` statement being there shouldn't hurt anything in AS, I would guess.

Comment: @MikeM. It seems to freak out about it.

Comment: Huh, I'd've thought AS would be smarter than that. Oh well, sounds like you've got a plan all the same.

Comment: @MikeM. I would think so as well. Perhaps AS2 will be. Anyway, unless I find a more efficient way to do things (which I really would prefer), I will just play a game of merging back and forth between two branches as necessary. If someone has a better way, please let me know. Thank you for your help Mike.

Comment: No problem. You still might wanna dig around in the gradle files for anything that specifies a certain build location. It'd be easier to just change that, rather than all the `import`s. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. I agree, but as I am very new to Android development, I do not yet know very much about Android Studio, AIDE, or Gradle.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could be more specific about what to look for, but I'm not very familiar with gradle yet myself. I think you wanna look for a `sourceSets` block, like is shown on [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html).

Comment: @MikeM. I found something that could be useful, but unfortunately it is for an earlier version of Android Studio and the instructions do not seem to be applicable. https://derfshaya.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/android-studio-0-2-0-and-the-gen-folder/

Comment: If you can find the analogous setting in your version of AS, that sounds like what you want. You could just include the folders that AIDE uses. I can't help ya there, though. I haven't played with AS since an early beta version.

Comment: @MikeM. New question in hopes that somebody will know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052072/change-structure-used-by-android-studio-to-create-the-gen-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an import with `R` with the name of your Project.
Like for example, my package name is - `com.xyz.app` then add an Import as `import com.xyz.app.R;`

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.  I had another error lost in the mass of "unknown entity" errors. Once I fixed it, the R file was auto-generated like usual.

Comment: @jamesc1101 Yes, this also happens most probably when there is an error in resource files i.e xml layouts or any other xml files :)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! It was in my main_layout.xml resource file.

Comment: @jamesc1101 haha, I have so much experience with AIDE as Its my primary IDE :P

Comment: It's my primary IDE as well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

This will happen when the **applicationId** does not match the package name in the app's **build.gradle** file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it turned out that I was missing another error that was preventing AIDE from completing the build. It was buried at the bottom of the mass of "Unknown entity 'R'" errors. Once I fixed that , it built like a dream and auto-generated the R file like normal. Yay!

[image: mass of errors]

[image: true error at bottom]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Delete the build (the one I encircled in blue ink.)
- Open the project again and refresh build