# Change Structure used by Android Studio to Create the 'gen' Folder

Tags: android, android-studio, aide-ide

I am writing an Android app that was started in Android Studio, but I would like to be able to work on the app using AIDE as well, but the structure used by AIDE to generate the 'gen' folder (where the R class is stored) is different from Android Studio, causing conflicts that can only be resolved by adding and removing import statements for the R class depending upon which IDE I am using. While I could do this, I would rather change the structure the Android Studio uses to generate this folder so that the project would be compatible with both IDEs without me needing to intervene. I do not want the change to be system-wide for AIDE, but rather only for this project. I could I go about doing this?

Comment: set `your_wanted_build_path` to `buildDir ` in top build.gradle. [The_reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340946/gradle-global-build-directory)

Comment: @Ninja I do not have any past experience with Gradle, and do not understand the instructions in the reference. I'm also not sure which build.gradle I should use since I have two of them.

Comment: hi, I commit my demo project about [change default gen folder](https://github.com/jiachenning/GradlePlayground/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: @Ninja This allows me to change where the data is stored, but it does not enable me to change the "generated" folder name to "gen", which I also need to do.

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to rename the "generated" folder, maybe use shell script is a workaround.